# Create View with 'STUFF' function - conversion failed nvarchar to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-view

I am confused I created a view that uses the  STUFF function on an int. It was working however I had to drop my table and reload it and now my view is not working. I receive the following error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' 5, 4' to data type int.`. I am loading the table from the same insert script that I used last time with the addition of one field which shouldn't have an affect. My create view script is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [AQB_OB].[GISREQUESTEDBURNS] 
AS

with conditions as 
(SELECT DISTINCT BD.[RequestedBurnsID]
,[ConditionsReasonsID] = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[ConditionsReasonsID]) FROM [AQB_OB].[BurnDecisions] WHERE [RequestedBurnsID]= BD.[RequestedBurnsID] ORDER BY [RequestedBurnsID] ASC
FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1 , 1, '') FROM
[AQB_OB].[BurnDecisions] BD)

SELECT RB.[RequestedBurnsID] AS REQUESTEDBURNID
  ,BUY.[BurnYear] AS BURNYEAR
  ,CY.[CurrentYear] AS CURRENTYEAR
  ,RB.[BurnSitesID] AS BURNSITESID
  ,[BurnerID] AS BURNERID
  ,[Contact] AS CONTACT
  ,[Latitude] AS LATITUDE
  ,[Longitude] AS LONGITUDE
  ,[BurnStartDate] AS BURNSTARTDATE
  ,[BurnEndDate] AS BURNENDDATE
  ,RB.[NumberPiles] AS NUMBERPILES
  ,[BurnDecision] AS BURNDECISION
  ,RB.[Comment] AS COMMENT
  ,CC.ConditionsReasonsID AS CONDITIONS

  FROM [AQB_MON].[AQB_OB].[RequestedBurns] RB
 inner join AQB_MON.[AQB_OB].[BurnSites] BS on RB.BurnSitesID = BS.BurnSitesID
 inner join AQB_MON.[AQB_OB].[Contacts] CT on RB.ContactsID = CT.ContactsID
 inner join AQB_MON.[AQB_OB].[BurnProject] BP on BP.BurnProjectID = BS.BurnProjectID
 inner join AQB_MON.[AQB_OB].[BurnYears] BUY on BUY.BurnYearID = BP.BurnYearID
 inner join AQB_MON.[AQB_OB].[CurrentYear] CY on CY.CurrentYearID = BUY.CurrentYearID
 full outer join  conditions CC on CC.RequestedBurnsID = RB.RequestedBurnsID 
 INNER JOIN [AQB_OB].[ConditionsReasons] CR ON CR.ConditionsReasonsID = CC.ConditionsReasonsID
GO
```

Comment: I think this is the reason. `INNER JOIN [AQB_OB].[ConditionsReasons] CR ON CR.ConditionsReasonsID = CC.ConditionsReasonsID` You are joining on the field you created to an integer field on `ConditionsReasons` table.

Comment: that was it. Once I removed that `INNER JOIN` my view worked -- Thank-you